# What happens to a softer material hitting a harder material at high speeds?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision

You often see action scenes in media, where a person is thrown so hard against a concrete wall, it breaks.

My question is if it's possible for a softer material to be accelerated to point where it would penetrate a harder material to a substantial amount. Does velocity even play a role in this? (Guns?) Or is it all material structure or hardness?

I guess I want to know which forces play a role at any given impact and what happens to both objects. Or does it all come down to material structure, flexibility and brittleness? I am really sorry if this is all over the place, I lack the physics education to phrase my question correctly.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what you mean by "high speed". High speeds on day-to-day human scales and speeds in excess of a few kilometers per second are quite different beasts.

Comment: Well, I am aware of that. I guess for the movie related question it's always subsonic speeds but I guess the whole concept in general? How and when (at which velocity) it changes. If it's possible to accelerate a "softer", as in less dense inferior material structure etc, object to a speed where it damages a "harder" object to a substantial amount or does it always break, no matter the velocity? (e.g. would a copper projectile always bend/break/compress even when shot at super sonic speeds?)

Comment: check out "the water jet channel" on youtube. Water goes through steel like butter, whether it is soft or hard water, too.

Comment: I guess that answers part of my question, but I am not talking about liquids!

Comment: A softer material simply means that impact time is longer.  this means that there is a lesser force of impact since change in momentum is equals to force times time.

Comment: Pieces of straw have been found embedded in telephone poles after a tornado passed through, indicating velocity is certainly a contributing factor.

Answer (score 0):

Soft means that the material is more easily compressed.  This would mean that the collision time of impact is greater.  Since change in momentum is $Ft$, and $t$ increases, it would mean force decreases.  So if you want to use a soft material to smash a wall, two things too take note are, of course the high velocity, and also the high coefficient of restitution.  This makes a rubber ball highly ideal.

Comment: This analysis is useful for speeds that are quite fast on the ordinary human scale, but fails at really high speeds. The issue is that molecule-molecule passing times get to be much smaller than the time-scale of inter-molecular relaxation in either body and the binding forces of either material pale before the dynamic close-approach forces. People in the high-speed collision business often say things like "everything is liquid"..

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the elastic property of the material like the maximum stress generated during the collision. If the stress generated is high enough to exceed the materials fracture point (it first have to exceed the yield strength for such to occur). Since stress is dependent on the speed of the particle colliding therefore yes it is possible to do so. But the act of collision not only generates stress in the wall but in the softer body. Therefore you have to keep this fact in mind that the stress in the soft body doesn't exceed it's fracture point but exceeds for the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Plastically deforming a chunk of, say, metal generates heat inside it. If the plastic deformation occurs so fast that there is no time for the heat to diffuse out, then the temperature of the material rises very fast and the softening point of the material is reached. Then the material flows like taffy, meaning that it goes "splat" when the thing it strikes is less easily deformed.

This is the mechanism behind *impact extrusion*, where a little pill of aluminum when smacked hard with a hammer can almost instantly be deformed into a sheet or a seamless tube. This is how aluminum drink cans, felt tip marker bodies, and cigar tubes are made.

Answer (score 0):

I came across something similiar like this which might help you with your question in this book: *Thinking Physics practical lessons in critical thinking by* L e w i s  C a r r o l l  E p s t e i n. You may find it here:

https://archive.org/details/ThinkingPhysicsPracticalLessonsInCriticalThinking_201808

On Page 81-82 you will find answers to the questions whether an aluminium bullet or a rubber bullet is more likely to knock over a block of wood and which one does more damage to the block.

The question you need to ask is how much momentum is transferred on impact versus how much energy is transferred on impact. More Energy in object = more Damage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to think that the soft material is so soft that it is something like a gas, I'm also gong to assume that the harder material is fixed in place, so it cannot move after the impact. If the softer material goes fast enough it will definitely cause some damage to the harder one, its kinetic energy must overcome the cohesive energy of the solid at the impact zone.

Note. I'm not 100% sure about this answer, I wish it was a comment instead. Can a mod or someone put it as a comment. Thx.